# R : how to get rid of all NaN values and replace them by 0 in a complex function / R file

Tags: r, nan, na, zero

How is it possible to get rid of all NaN values and replace them by zero (0) in a complex function / whole R file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace NaN values in a list with zero (0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581743/replace-nan-values-in-a-list-with-zero-0)

Comment: Agree it needs to be closed but more because of a lack of clarity. The phrase "complex function" really has no  meaning.

Comment: @BondedDust is there a possibility to replace NaN by 0 on a whole data set?

Comment: Don't really know since "the whole dataset" remains undescribed. Have your tried:     `dset[is.na(dset)]' <- 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you mean by a whole file/complex function, but depending on the data type you're storing the file with, it's pretty easy using is.na():

```
df <- data.frame(A = rep(1, 5), B = rep(1,5))
df$B[1] <- NA
df$A[3] <- NA
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```